# what is difference between thread.sleep(9000l) and thread.sleep(9000)

Tags: java

What is difference between `Thread.sleep(9000l);` and `Thread.sleep(9000);`

Does it make and difference in sleep time of thread or it is one and same.

Comment: It is the same. 9000L is just a convention within java to define that the number you're working with is of type long. Same goes for e.g float (0.1f)

Comment: No difference. There is only one overload of `Thread.sleep`: `Thread.sleep(long)`. The second form specifies an `int` argument, but it will be automatically widened to `long`.

Comment: Note that it may be better to use the `L` suffix, rather than `l`, to specify a long literal: the `l` looks a lot like a `1` in some fonts.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference at all.

There is only one overload of `Thread.sleep`: `Thread.sleep(long)`. The second form specifies an `int` argument, but it will be automatically widened to `long`.

Since `9000` is a constant expression, the compiler rewrites it to `9000L`:

```
public void one() throws InterruptedException {
  Thread.sleep(9000);
}

public void two() throws InterruptedException {
  Thread.sleep(9000L);
}
```

decompiles to...

```
  public void one() throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 9000l
       3: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Thread.sleep:(J)V
       6: return

  public void two() throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
    Code:
       0: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 9000l
       3: invokestatic  #4                  // Method java/lang/Thread.sleep:(J)V
       6: return
```

Identical bytecode, so no difference.